# Erlang installation giving erlang-mode is broken error

Tags: erlang, elixir, distributed-computing, distributed

I am trying to install Elixir from the [elixir website](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#unix-and-unix-like) on Ubuntu 14.04. I get the following error when I execute `$ sudo apt-get install esl-erlang`. Can anyone help me out here ?

```
$ sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
esl-erlang is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgconf2-4 python-requests-whl python-setuptools-whl python-six-whl
  python-urllib3-whl python-wheel
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 406 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up erlang-mode (1:21.0.5-1) ...
ERROR: erlang-mode is broken - called emacs-package-install as a new-style add-on, but has no compat file.
Install emacsen-common for emacs23
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs23
Wrote /etc/emacs23/site-start.d/00debian-vars.elc
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/debian-startup.elc
Install emacsen-common for emacs24
emacsen-common: Handling install of emacsen flavor emacs24
Wrote /etc/emacs24/site-start.d/00debian-vars.elc
Wrote /usr/share/emacs24/site-lisp/debian-startup.elc
Install erlang-mode for emacs
Install erlang-mode for emacs23
install/erlang: Handling install for emacsen flavor emacs23
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/erlang/erlang-edoc.elc
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/erlang/erlang-eunit.elc
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/erlang/erlang-flymake.elc
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/erlang/erlang-skels-old.elc
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/erlang/erlang-skels.elc
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/erlang/erlang-start.elc
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/erlang/erlang.elc
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/erlang/erlang_appwiz.elc

In toplevel form:
erldoc.el:64:1:Error: Cannot open load file: cl-lib
Wrote /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/erlang/path.elc
ERROR: install script from erlang-mode package failed
dpkg: error processing package erlang-mode (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 erlang-mode
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have both emacs23 and emacs24 installed. The failure is happening when trying to build for emacs23. Unless you really want emacs23 for some reason, remove it and then it should install fine:

```
sudo apt-get remove emacs23
```

It is possible you might have to delete some of the other emacs23-* packages by hand.

Comment: You are right! The source file has `Package-Requires: ((emacs "24.1"))`, so Emacs 23 is not supported. Seems like a bug in the `erlang-mode` package, in that it should exclude Emacs 23 when installing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is causing your errors, but you could try [ASDF](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) with the [Elixir plugin](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-elixir). This allows you to install multiple versions of Elixir and its dependencies, and uses your user environment with [shims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shim_(computing)) instead of installing to system directories. This avoids many of the dependency and permission problems that comes with performing a single system-level installation.

Answer (score 0):

This problem only affects the `erlang-mode` package, which adds support for editing Erlang code in Emacs.  If you're not using Emacs (or not developing Erlang in it), you can just uninstall that package:

```
sudo apt remove erlang-mode
```

---

As noted in [Penguin Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52109433/113848), this happens when installing `erlang-mode` on a system using Emacs 23, as `erlang-mode` only supports Emacs 24 or newer.  (Looks like this is a bug in the package: it shouldn't try to compile itself for unsupported Emacs versions.)  If you do want to use `erlang-mode` in Emacs, I'd suggest running Emacs 24 and installing the Erlang mode from [MELPA](https://melpa.org/).